# Generating 2 comma-separated lists from list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, performance

Could this code:

```
var a = new StringBuilder();
var b = new StringBuilder();
var kvps = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, object>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<Guid, object>(Guid.NewGuid(), 1),
    new KeyValuePair<Guid, object>(Guid.NewGuid(), "hello")
};
for (var c = 0; c < kvps.Count; c++)
{
    a.Append(kvps[c].Key);
    b.Append(kvps[c].Value);
    if (c >= kvps.Count - 1) continue;
    a.Append(",");
    b.Append(",");
}
```

be improved in terms of performance to achieve this:

```
a = e1b7978c-127f-4a5f-a17b-737e03484172,cbbd1573-950c-4ca4-94b7-72a08b4a61d0
b = 1,hello
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Performance here will only matter if the input List is large. There are two things that can be done to make the output loop faster:

1. initialize the starting capacity of the StringBuilder to match your expectations of what size it will need to be.

   In this case, you know the GUUID's are 36 characters long, with a comma, makes it 37. You should initialize that StringBuilder to `... new StringBuilder(37 * kvps.Count);`. Similarly, if you have an approximate size of the average length for the other Stringbuilder, then double-it, and use it as the initial capacity constructor.
2. If the loop happens (very) often, you can get a very slight performance improvement by doing the following (removing the if condition from inside the loop):

   ```
   foreach (KeyValuePair kv in kvps)
   {
       a.Append(kv.Key);
       a.Append(",");
       b.Append(kv.Value);
       b.Append(",");
   }
   // remove the trailing comma.
   if (kvps.Count > 0) {
       a.Length = a.Length - 1;
       b.Length = b.Length - 1;
   }
   ```

It should go without saying that the names `a` and `b` are bad names for the `StringBuilder` instances ....

Comment: Thanks. Nice trick to remove the trailing comma, which allows me to use foreach. Please note the names were just chosen for this example but yes even here I should use better names in the future (-:

Comment: I suspect that the JIT compiler (which makes intelligent guesses about `if`s) will probably perform almost exactly as well as this method, but you have to test it to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist that the type remain `List<KeyValuePair<Guid, object>>` you could still make use  of `String.Join()` by using `Select()`, a LINQ extension method::

```
// at top of file: using System.Linq;

String keys = String.Join(",", kvps.Select(kv=>kv.Key.ToString()));
String values = String.Join(",", kvps.Select(kv=>kv.Value.ToString()));
```

The downside is that there are potentially two passes over the list (I say "potentially" because there's a good chance that the optimizer in the compiler or JIT may detect the parallelism and exploit it).

Answer (score 2):

As a GUID should be unique you should think about using a `Dictionary<GUID,object>` instead of your `List<KeyValuePair<GUID,object>>` .

If using a Dictionary is possible you can get the comma separated list by using the [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Dictionary<Guid, object> kvps = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();

kvps.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), 1);
kvps.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "hello");

String keys = String.Join(",", kvps.Keys);
String values = String.Join(",", kvps.Values);
```

Comment: This won't work if order is important, as the order of the keys in the dictionary is unspecified.

Comment: Also it would loop twice potentially ...

Comment: It may loop twice or it may not; it depends how intelligent the optimizer (either at compilation or JIT) is feeling that day.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are essentially performing a fold of the list and returning a tuple you could express just that in the code which would also be rather short and still only loop trough the list once

```
var builders = kvps.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new StringBuilder(),new StringBuilder(),
                        (acc,kv) => {
                                      acc.Item1.Append("," + kv.Key);
                                      acc.Item2.Append("," + kv.Value)
                                      return acc;
                                    });
a = builders.Item1.ToString().Substring(1);
b = builders.Item2.ToString().Substring(1);
```

Whether or not this can compare speedwise with other implementations depend on how well the optimizer can optimize the code

Comment: I really like this method, but unfortunately the code required to implement it is a little verbose. Also I think that for memory alignment purposes it's more efficient to have the `","` be a suffix instead of a prefix.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it is verbose. It's a shame the same implementation in F# is a lot nicer (The inspiration came from there) tuples just aren't natural in C#